# jQuery and native js do not agree on data attribute

Tags: jquery

The jQuery attribute set does not agree with the attribute as set by native js and apparently they exist differently and simultaneously.  Can anyone tell me what is going on?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('attributed').setAttribute('data-foo','mydiv2'); 

    $('#attributed').data('foo','mydiv4');   

    // jQuery thinks it's mydiv 4 
    alert($('#attributed').data('foo'));     

    // native thinks it's mydiv 2! 
    alert(document.getElementById('attributed').getAttribute('data-foo'));
});
```

Comment: IIRC jQuery keeps the data set in a plain JS object in memory and does not actually write it to the DOM.

Comment: Yup - this is the case https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `.data()` only reads the actual attribute off the DOM element if there is nothing already set in its own `.data()` data structure for that element and that key.  So, once you've set a value with jQuery's `.data()` for that key it will have a different value than the actual HTML attribute on the element.

This is done for a couple reasons.  Earlier browsers had memory leak issues if javascript objects were associated directly with a DOM object (as a property).  And, pure attributes can only be strings.  jQuery's `.data()` doesn't have either of these issues.